# Installing ASP.NET MVC 4 on a server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How does one go about installing ASP.NET MVC 4 on a *server*. The Web Platform Installer insists on installing all kinds of Visual Studio 2010 stuff. I don't see a "server only" installation. For example, it wants to install "Visual Studio 2010 Core SP1" and "Visual Web Developer Express".

Comment: Wrong StackExchange site. Try here next time. http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You should not be doing that. You should be using the ASP.NET MVC 4 nuget package which will add all needed assemblies as Copy Local Always so when you deploy it will include them all as part of the site/application

Comment: To add: This is a big deal because once you have it in GAC it will always override the local version which can lead to bizzare problems when updates come!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Get the standalone installer from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Comment: This is not a great option.  The standalone installer is intended to be installed with Visual Studio 2010.  We don't run Visual Studio 2010.  We need an installer that at most gets the MVC v4 assemblies in to the GAC.  They are in the GAC on the build servers, so don't get copied to the bin at compile time.  It's frustrating that Microsoft still isn't thinking about operational concerns.

Comment: @splatteredbits, the installer doesn't need VS, I use it on our servers for deployment and this works perfectly. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried it.  But it makes our operations team nervous.  They don't know what kind of side-affects the installer has: what additional stuff it installs that they don't know about.

Comment: @splatteredbits, if your operations team is any good they can monitor the changes made by the install, and by doing so on a virtual test machine they don't run any risk whatsoever. I bet that many of the hotfixes delivered via Windows Update are more suspect in what they do than this installer.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but that standalone installer in the link fails with "This product requires VWD 2010 SP1".

Comment: @SteveOwen, I just tried the [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) again and it worked perfectly on a clean server. The server has **no** VS, VWD, SDK or so installed. Make sure that there isn't an old version of VS or similar on that machine, which may trigger the VS installation code in the setup.

Comment: Yeah, don't use the web platform installer for installing on the server. Use the above standalone mvc4 installer. Works great for me :)

Comment: I don't know why i have to install sql server express too, even why its a part of this web platform installation wizard. Does anyone sorted out how to skip it?

Comment: @stenly: Just as Moulde also noted: don't use the web platform installer on the server. THe standalone works fine. That being said, newer versions of ASP.NET MVC are typically delivered as NuGet packages and not installed on the server anyways.

Comment: @Lucero r u sure? seems to me like a useless dlls duplications by each new web app deployed on the server
instead of that you might have libraries in GAC or in program files

Comment: @stenly: Yeah, it is duplication to some extent. However, copying the DLLs with the app prevents version mismatches and allows for more flexible deployment, updating and hotfixing. Also, starting with Windows 2012 Server, you can deduplicate the filesystem (NTFS) which will avoid duplicated storage even if the same DLLs are used thousands of times.

Answer (score 9):

The safest thing to do would be to mark your reference to System.Web.Mvc as "copy local = true" in the reference's properties window. When you do a deploy, it will get copied into your bin folder.

It feels a bit backwards, but there you go.

Comment: Or more approriately, install the MVC nuget package, which does this for you. Which, in turn, is not at all backwards, because it allows coexistence of different versions, so each project can be sure it gets the version it was built against. Having it in the GAC would override this.

Answer (score 0):

I would install and run on local host, then use Visual Studio's "publish" to publish it to a web server.  You can install it via http://www.asp.net/mvc.  If you're asking how to install it on IIS, then read this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx